# How to count the number of checkboxes checked using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to get the number of checkBoxes checked with using the information from an array but I keep getting undefined. I have to use an array, a switch, and must be in JavaScript for this project. I can't use any other programming Language.

How can I get my function to correctly add the checked boxes?
I am also not sure on how I could implement a switch into this function.+

Please help, I've been working on this for about 4 hours, searching everywhere to find a helpful answer.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="frmCareer" method="get" action="prjFormEvent.js">
<table id="tblCareer">

<th>Directions: Check of the items you think you would enjoy in each section.<br /> Mark as many items that apply.</th>

<tr><td><strong><label id="lblRealistic">
"R" Section</label></strong>
<div id="realisticTotal"></div>
<br />
<input type="checkbox"
name="chkRealistic"
onclick="getRealistic()"
value="chkRealistic1">Repair a car
<br />
<input type="checkbox"
name="chkRealistic"
onclick="getRealistic()"
value="chkRealistic2">Do wood working
<br />
<input type="checkbox"
name="chkRealistic"
onclick="getRealistic()"
value="chkRealistic3">Refinish furniture
<br />
<input type="checkbox"
name="chkRealistic"
onclick="getRealistic()"
value="chkRealistic4">Explore a forest
<br />
</tr></td>

      </table><!--End of tblWhichCareer-->
   </form><!--End of frmWhichCareer-->

</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript

```
Global Variables
var getCareer = new Array();
getCareer["chkRealistic1"] = 1;
getCareer["chkRealistic2"] = 1;
getCareer["chkRealistic3"] = 1;
getCareer["chkRealistic4"] = 1;

function getRealistic()
{
    var rTotal = 0;
    var selectedRealistic = document.forms["frmCareer"]["chkRealistic"];

    rTotal = getCareer[selectedRealistic.value]

    document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML = rTotal+ "/9 Checked"
}//End of function getRealisticCareer()
```

Comment: try using this `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length`

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar You should put that as the answer, since it is *the* answer. :)

Comment: I missed by few mins. You should have really put it in the answers :)

Comment: For sure next time.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the fact that this line

```
var selectedRealistic = document.forms["frmCareer"]["chkRealistic"];
```

returns an array of checkboxes with the name **chkRealistic** (in your example, all four of them).

Instead of assigning the result of the **getCareer** function to **rTotal**, you should iterate through the array of HTMLInput in **selectedRealistic** checking for the .**checked** property.

```
var rTotal = 0;
var selectedRealistic = document.forms["frmCareer"]["chkRealistic"];

for (var sel = 0; sel < selectedRealistic.length; sel++)
{
  if (selectedRealistic[sel].checked)
        rTotal += getCareer[selectedRealistic[sel].value]
}

document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML = rTotal+ "/9 Checked"
```

You can check a running example here: http://codepen.io/pabloapa/pen/jPNPNg

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML =  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="chkRealistic"]:checked').length + "/9 Checked";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getRealistic()
{
var rTotal = 0;

for(i=0; i<document.forms[0].chkRealistic.length; i++){
    if(document.forms[0].chkRealistic.item(i).checked){
        rTotal++;
    }
}

document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML = rTotal+ "/9 Checked"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this also on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/085ZtojBgvumktHwQSGf?p=preview

```
<form id="frmCareer" method="get" action="prjFormEvent.js">
    <table id="tblCareer">
      <tr>
        <th>Directions: Check of the items you think you would enjoy in each section.
          <br />Mark as many items that apply.</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong><label id="lblRealistic">
"R" Section</label></strong>
          <div id="realisticTotal"></div>
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onchange="getRealistic(this)" value="chkRealistic1">Repair a car
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onchange="getRealistic(this)" value="chkRealistic2">Do wood working
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onchange="getRealistic(this)" value="chkRealistic3">Refinish furniture
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onchange="getRealistic(this)" value="chkRealistic4">Explore a forest
          <br />
        </td>
      </tr>


    </table>
    <!--End of tblWhichCareer-->
  </form>
  <!--End of frmWhichCareer-->
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var getCareer = new Array();
    getCareer["chkRealistic1"] = 0;
    getCareer["chkRealistic2"] = 0;
    getCareer["chkRealistic3"] = 0;
    getCareer["chkRealistic4"] = 0;

    function getRealistic(cbox) {
      var rTotal = 0;
      var key = cbox.value;
      getCareer[key] = cbox.checked ? 1 : 0;

      for (var key in getCareer) {
        rTotal += getCareer[key];

      }

      document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML = rTotal + "/9 Checked"
    } //End of function getRealisticCareer()
  </script>
```